# About the toolbox

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio 2008. Some of the categories in the toolbox are disabled I don't know why. For instance, the standard category. I need to use dropdownlist control but all the tools are greyed out. One more weird thing, Its working on web form application but not on window form application.

I reinstalled the VS2008 but in vain. What all I have already tried:

1. I reset all settings in Import and export settings under the tool menu
2. devenv /resetsettings
3. devenv /safemode
4. devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

All these in vain. I can't find the way out. Please help

Comment: Silly question, but you are differentiating between Web controls and Windows Forms Controls?

Comment: I dont know. I have just started learning asp.net

Comment: do u mean we cant add a dropdownlist control on a window form ?

Comment: Drop down list is an ASP.NET control, but not a Windows Form Control. Windows Forms it's called a Combo Box

Comment: Alright. If this is so then how do I add FileUpload control to my windows form ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to drop the content in the code page? Cause obviously,tools can be dropped in the designer page.

Comment: No. I am not that noob @kakarott but do u agree with dane ??

Comment: Yeah..He's right, ddl is called a combobox when it comes to Windows Form.

Comment: And what about FileUpload control then ? I want to use it in my window application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Controls and when they are applied. I suggest you go through some basics on Visual Studio and understand the difference.

Here is a fantastic article on [C# Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1465/Beginning-C-Chapter-13-Using-Windows-Form-Controls)

For FileUpload control which is a Web Control; you need to use OpenFileDialog in Windows.Form.

Comment: Thanx alot sir. This was great help

Answer (score 1):

I can't post this as a comment so I'm posting it as an answer. For browse button in web form, you have an `Open File Dialog` control,you have to drag and drop it to your form and have to assign it to a simple button.

Here is how you can assign an Open File Dialog to a button :

```
     private void btnBrowes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog.Title = "Open File";
        }
```

Read more Here :

[**Open File Dialog**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) 
[**C# Browse File**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog)

Comment: Thanx. Can we store this file that we'll open using open file dialog somewhere in a folder like we do in web form using file upload control ?